# How do I set shape density in PhysX 3.1?

Tags: physx

I'm using PhysX 3.1. I need to give shapes different densities (there are several shapes for my single rigid actor). I know that the shape's density can be set by `NxShapeDesc::density` in PhysX 2.8, but I can't find such an interface in PhysX 3.1.

I know mass properties can be set in PhysX 3.1 just as the snowman example in the SDK. Is there a direct interface to set density for each shape?

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly set shape density in PhysX 3.1, but you can achieve the same results using the helper methods `PxRigidBodyExt::updateMassAndInertia`, and `setMassAndUpdateInertia`. They permit you to specify densities indirectly.

Comment: Thanks, I know that we can set the mass as this method just as the sdk's example, I just want to set density directly to shapes.

Comment: i think this is impossible in 3.x

Comment: Yes, this is impossible in 3.1, but PhysX add this feature again in 3.2